# My program has no output when I attempt to find the lowest value of 3 objects

Tags: java

My task is to create 3 CellPhone objects, and to take in user input. The user enters the manufacturer, the model, and the price. Im supposed to then find the lowest price of the 3 phones. This is my code

```
public class CellPhone {

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

private static String manufact;
private static String model;
private static double price;

public CellPhone(String manufact, String model, double price) {

    manufact = CellPhone.manufact;
    model = CellPhone.model;
    price = CellPhone.price;

}

public String getManufact() {
    return manufact;
}

public void setManufact(String manufact) {
    CellPhone.manufact = manufact;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    CellPhone.model = model;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    CellPhone.price = price;
}
```

And then my main method is

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //I created 9 different scanners, to use 3 as arguments for each of the 3 objects

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String manufact = scan.next();

    String model = scan.next();

    double price = scan.nextDouble();

    String manufact1 = scan.next();

    String model1 = scan.next();

    double price1 = scan.nextDouble();

    String manufact2 = scan.next();

    String model2 = scan.next();

    double price2 = scan.nextDouble();


    //objects 
    CellPhone cell1 = new CellPhone(manufact, model, price);

    CellPhone cell2 = new CellPhone(manufact1, model1, price1);

    CellPhone cell3 = new CellPhone(manufact2, model2, price2);


    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("bestprice.txt");

    // finds lowest retail price for each object

    if (cell1.getPrice() < cell2.getPrice()) {
        if (cell1.getPrice() < cell3.getPrice()) {
            outputFile.println(
                    "The lowest price is:\n" + cell1.getManufact() + cell1.getModel() + "for $" + cell1.getPrice());
            System.out.println(
                    "The lowest price is:\n" + cell1.getManufact() + cell1.getModel() + "for $" + cell1.getPrice());
        }
    }

     if (cell2.getPrice() < cell1.getPrice()) {
        if (cell2.getPrice() < cell3.getPrice()) {
            outputFile.println(
                    "The lowest price is:\n" + cell2.getManufact() + cell2.getModel() + "for $" + cell2.getPrice());
            System.out.println(
                    "The lowest price is:\n" + cell2.getManufact() + cell2.getModel() + "for $" + cell2.getPrice());
        }
    }

     if (cell3.getPrice() < cell1.getPrice()) {
        if (cell3.getPrice() < cell2.getPrice()) {
            outputFile.println(
                    "The lowest price is:\n" + cell3.getManufact() + cell3.getModel() + "for $" + cell3.getPrice());
            System.out.println(
                    "The lowest price is:\n" + cell3.getManufact() + cell3.getModel() + "for $" + cell3.getPrice());
        }
    }

    outputFile.close();
}
```

my program has no output whatsoever. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you share the inputs you gave ??

Comment: I don't think you want to use static fields

Comment: @ScaryWombat Good eye...

Comment: Your program is not printing anything because all objects are identical (see link above) and you're not printing anything for equal prices.

Comment: @shmosel thank you!